# BizTalk 2016 orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016, biztalk-orchestrations

I need to recognize a file type and make a decision in a decision shape according to a file type.

I will receive 2 types of file: csv and JPG. So if it is CSV - send here, if JPG - send another way. So my question is how to recognize file type in decision shape in a orchestration?

Comment: yes, thank you so much for info. Sorry for the delay. In Azure Logic app it's so easy, just to add checking "if file name contains...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the filename from the context property called BTS.ReceivedFileName on the message.

```
FileName = InputMessage(BTS.ReceivedFileName);
```

Then you will probably need to make a call to a C# method Path.GetExtension

```
extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
```

Then you can have a decision shape based on the extension